# How can I add a small claims judgment to someone's credit report?

Tags: small-claims-court

I won a judgement in small claims court against a tenant two years ago.  The person has not paid.  I'd like to know how to put the judgement on their credit report.

Comment: Laws and procedures vary around the world. If you would like a specific answer to your question then please add the relevant jurisdiction tag.

Comment: **Depending on the Jurisdiction**, you can or you can't or it might be automatic.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to hire a collection agency to collect the debt (for a fee of course), because collection agencies routinely include debts that they are collecting in credit reports.

Credit reporting agencies differ in what other kinds of debts they will report. Recording a judgment lien in real property records will trigger a credit report entry with some agencies, but not others. Some agencies report all judgments entered in courts, but others don't. You could also contact a credit reporting agency and ask it if it will simply report your judgment without further action if you send them a copy.